# Signaling periodic ajax call to terminate

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an `onclick` event for a `radio button` that calls a function which launches period AJAX calls to some url

Example in MVC cshtml view

```
<script>
        function onClick(selectedRowId) {
            GetData("/home/GetData/" + selectedRowId);
        };
</script>
```

Ajax call

```
function GetData(url) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: onSuccess,
        error: onError,
        complete: function (xhr, status) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                GetData(url);
            }, 10000);
        }
    });
}
```

When a different `radio button` is selected I need to call the `onClick` method with the selected `radio button id` and this again initiates a call to the url with the different id.

However, I would like the previous AJAX function call to terminate since the AJAX `onSuccess` method updates an html element with the data retrieved for that specific selected Id.

Any way to signal the previous call to terminate before launching new one ?

One way to solve this could be

a) Not make id as a paramter to the url call then

b) in the `onClick` method send a call to Server to set the Id variable (this makes the server aware that all data must be returned for that Id)

c) Then ensure that ajax function is called only once and server will change data returned based on Id information conveyed to it in (a)

Not sure if the server round trip is worth it here for every button click.

Answer (score 0):

The best I can think is each time onClick fired, it needs to cache the selectedRowIndex which you are only interested in the latest selected one.  As you mention, the server need to return that ID back.  That way on your onSuccess function, you only need to process returns that matched ID and ignore any other.

I don't think you can literally stops previous ajax. You don't have access to the previous ajax object any more.  Just ignore previous responses.